# Download by scp with net connection problem

Tags: linux, scp

I want to download log file from my Amazon server by `scp` command

```
scp -i /home/user/Downloads/new-bots-key  ***@**ip**:/*****/loggins/2019-07-09.log /home/user/Downloads/2019-07-09.log
```

I have a connection loss.

> Connection to 174.***.***.*** port 22: Broken pipe

or it holds on this

> 2019-07-09.log                                 10%  560KB 112.7KB/s   00:40 ETA

The connection problem is not my question(but tips are welcome).

I want to know how can I download a file with restarting when downloading has a failure.

Comment: you can do rsync with infinite loop...

Comment: How can I add the condition of the ending of loop? It will rewrite my good file on one of the next iteration

Comment: Have you considered using a synchronization tool? For example, `syncthing`. Such tools account for broken network connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SYNC_STATUS=1 
while [[ "$SYNC_STATUS" -ne 0 ]]
do
   sshpass -p "$password" rsync -a $sourcePath $destinationPath  
   SYNC_STATUS=$?
done
```

the loop will continue until exit code of rsync is 0(success).

Comment: How can I use private ssh key instead of password in your command?

Comment: Sorry. I will check your answer after the holidays. Do not worry, reputation will catch up with you.